# Help on proof of claim about $\limsup$ of real sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{p_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. I would like to show that $~lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sup~p_n< \infty$ if and only if $\{p_n\}$ is bounded above.

Let $E:=\{\text{limits of subsequences }\{p_{n_k}\}\}$

By definition $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sup~p_n=\sup E$.

It is known that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sup~p_n=p< \infty$ then $~\{p_n\}$ must converge, say $~p_n \rightarrow p^*$, for if $p_n \rightarrow \infty$, then $\sup E= \infty$.

$~p_n \rightarrow p^*$ if and only if every subsequence of $\{p_n\}$ converges to $p^*$. Now, since $E$ is closed by a theorem in the textbook, we must have $p^*=p=\sup E$.

I am stuck here. I have not shown anything, but I was thinking that I could somehow show $p$ is an upper bound of $\{p_n\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

limsup is the sup of all subsequences. If p_n is not bounded above, one subsequence is this unbounded sequence. This shows that p_n bounded -> limsup p_n < infinity.

If limsup < infinity then all subsequences are bounded. If p_n was unbounded then there would be a unbounded subsequence which is not possible by our assumption.

This proves both directions.